# Video output on audio port

Tags: audio, video

I've seen phone that are able to output video from standard Android audio port or jack.

Given this, I am thinking of what are the possibilities of doing an android app that can output video from the standard Android audio port?

I am not sure but maybe those existing Android phones have video out hardware interfaced to the microphone part of the audio port (just assuming), and I am also assuming that the Android phone microphone input is not capable of outputting signals in any way we tweak it.

So I am thinking of outputting video signal through either the L or R audio port. If this is the only feasible solution, what are the things that should be considered?

Comment: Some devices has 3,5mm AV connector, 4 wires: ground, sound left, sound right, video. In some order. It should simply push current screen contents out through video wire.

Comment: You can't drive it through audio as video signal requires several MHz carrier and most probably those audio chips will not even near MHz. This means you would need audio stream with at least 12000000Hz sampling rate for video signal.